# Tikz - create rectangle with same width as the picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, backgrounds

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,shapes.geometric,calc,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% Headers        
\node (header1) {\large HeaderOne};
\node[right=of header1] (header2) {\large HeaderTwo};

% Text
\node[below=of header1.west, anchor=west] (text1) {Short text};
\node[below=of header2.west, anchor=west] (text2) {A long line of text. A long line of text. A long line of text. A long line of text.};

% Background
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\node [fill=gray!20, draw=black, fit=(current bounding box.north west) (current bounding box.south east)] {};
\end{pgfonlayer}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces this: [image]

However, in addition, I would like to create a **rectangle as background for HeaderOne and HeaderTwo**, which also spans the width of the entire picture, a bit like this (please ignore the bad painting around the text itself; it should be drawn on the background layer):
[image]

I have tried using 'background top' from the pgf manual in conjunction with 'background rectangle', but this does not look good when you want to have drawn a black line (border) around everything as well (the border does not fit the entire picture then).

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just use a table for that?

Comment: I have further elements in my actual tikz picture (i.e. code which is inherent to tikz, and would not fit into a table). Sorry I didnt mention that.

Comment: My suggestion is to make a table and place this table inside a node

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add another `fit` node and do not forget `inner sep=0pt`.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,shapes.geometric,calc,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={minimum height=5ex}]

% Headers        
\node (header1) {\large HeaderOne};
\node[right=of header1] (header2) {\large HeaderTwo};

% Text
\node[below=0pt of header1.south west, anchor=north west] (text1) {Short text};
\node[below=0pt of header2.south west, anchor=north west] (text2) {A long line of text. A long line of text. A long line of text. A long line of text.};

% Background
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\node [fill=gray!20, draw=black, fit=(current bounding box.north west) (current bounding box.south east), inner sep=0pt] {};
\node [fill=red, draw=black, fit=(header1)(header2)(current bounding box.north east), inner sep=0pt] {};
\end{pgfonlayer}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @JouleV That depends on `below of`, I'll improve soon.

Comment: @JouleV Yes, that's also a good solution, see my now.

Comment: @CarLaTeX: Thanks for your solution - exactly what I needed.

Comment: @PS. You're welcome! Thank you for accepting my answer!

Answer (score 3):

Why don't use a simple table for that?

```
\documentclass[margin=3]{standalone}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    \hline 
    \rowcolor{red}\large HeaderOne & \large HeaderTwo\\\hline 
    \rowcolor{gray!20} Short text & A long line of text. A long line of text. A long line of text. A long line of text.\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to use this table inside a Ti*k*Z picture, simply place it inside a node.

```
\documentclass[margin=3,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\tikz\node{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    \hline 
    \rowcolor{red}\large HeaderOne & \large HeaderTwo\\\hline 
    \rowcolor{gray!20} Short text & A long line of text. A long line of text. A long line of text. A long line of text.\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}};
\end{document}
```

With pure Ti*k*Z it is also not that complicated. No need of PGF layers. However, I don't recommend this way.

```
\documentclass[margin=3,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0pt,inner sep=7pt]
\node[text width=3cm,font=\large\color{white},fill=red] (header1) {HeaderOne};
\node[text width=3cm,below=of header1,fill=gray!20] (text1) {Short text};
\node[text width=13cm,font=\large\color{white},fill=red,right=-\pgflinewidth of header1] (header2) {HeaderTwo};
\node[text width=13cm,below=of header2,fill=gray!20] (text2) {A long line of text. A long line of text. A long line of text. A long line of text.};
\draw (header1.north west) -- (header2.north east)
    (header1.south west) -- (header2.south east)
    (text1.south west) -- (text2.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]